# How to sample a plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, sampling

The plot in MATLAB looks like this:

[image]

The code to generate this is very simple:

```
 y = [0 18 450];
 x = [0 5.3 6.575];
 plot(x,y);
```

How could I know the values of 119 equally spaced discrete points on this plot?

Comment: Are you looking for equally spaced points or any random set of points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple MATLAB plots, the points are connected together by simple linear interpolation.  Simply put, a straight line is drawn between each pair of points.  You can't physically get these points from the graph other than those you used to plot the points (at least not easily...).

If you however do desire 119 points at equally spaced intervals that **would theoretically** be obtained from the above set of 4 points, you can use the [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function to do so:

```
y = [0 18 450];
x = [0 5.3 6.575]
yy = interp1(x, y, linspace(min(x),max(x),119), 'linear');
```

`interp1` performs linear (note the `'linear'` flag at the end...) interpolation given a set of key points defined by `x` and `y` points and a set of `x` points to use to interpolate between the key `x` points to generate the interpolated `y` points stored in `yy`.  [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) in this case generates a linearly increasing array from the smallest value in `x` to the largest value in `x` with 119 of these points.

Here's a running example with your data:

```
>> format compact;
>> y = [0 18 450]; 
>> x = [0 5.3 6.575];
>> yy = interp1(x, y, linspace(min(x),max(x),119), 'linear');
>> yy
yy =
  Columns 1 through 8
         0    0.1892    0.3785    0.5677    0.7570    0.9462    1.1354    1.3247
  Columns 9 through 16
    1.5139    1.7031    1.8924    2.0816    2.2709    2.4601    2.6493    2.8386
  Columns 17 through 24
    3.0278    3.2171    3.4063    3.5955    3.7848    3.9740    4.1633    4.3525
  Columns 25 through 32
    4.5417    4.7310    4.9202    5.1094    5.2987    5.4879    5.6772    5.8664
  Columns 33 through 40
    6.0556    6.2449    6.4341    6.6234    6.8126    7.0018    7.1911    7.3803
  Columns 41 through 48
    7.5696    7.7588    7.9480    8.1373    8.3265    8.5157    8.7050    8.8942
  Columns 49 through 56
    9.0835    9.2727    9.4619    9.6512    9.8404   10.0297   10.2189   10.4081
  Columns 57 through 64
   10.5974   10.7866   10.9759   11.1651   11.3543   11.5436   11.7328   11.9220
  Columns 65 through 72
   12.1113   12.3005   12.4898   12.6790   12.8682   13.0575   13.2467   13.4360
  Columns 73 through 80
   13.6252   13.8144   14.0037   14.1929   14.3822   14.5714   14.7606   14.9499
  Columns 81 through 88
   15.1391   15.3283   15.5176   15.7068   15.8961   16.0853   16.2745   16.4638
  Columns 89 through 96
   16.6530   16.8423   17.0315   17.2207   17.4100   17.5992   17.7885   17.9777
  Columns 97 through 104
   34.6540   53.5334   72.4128   91.2921  110.1715  129.0508  147.9302  166.8096
  Columns 105 through 112
  185.6889  204.5683  223.4477  242.3270  261.2064  280.0857  298.9651  317.8445
  Columns 113 through 119
  336.7238  355.6032  374.4826  393.3619  412.2413  431.1206  450.0000
```